# iOS 15 app not launching in killed state with location change

Tags: swift, gps, location, appdelegate, ios15

I have added the background modes for location in my app [SS here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEINC.png)

But still, the app does not launch with the launch options key

> UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.location

Here is my app delegate code,

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    addItem(name: "LaunchOptions: \(String(describing: launchOptions))")
    if let launchOptions = launchOptions {
        if launchOptions[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.location] != nil {
            startLocationMonitoring()
        }
    }
    print("LaunchOptions: \(String(describing: launchOptions))")
    return true
}

func startLocationMonitoring() {
    locationManager?.delegate = nil
    locationManager = nil
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager?.delegate = self
    locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
    locationManager?.distanceFilter = 1.0 // meters
    locationManager?.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    locationManager?.activityType = .otherNavigation
    locationManager?.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
    authStatusCheck()
    locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    print(locations)
    if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate) {
        for location in locations {
            appDelegate.addItem(newLocation: location)
        }
    }
}
```

addItem function adds the location change or the logs to core data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now you get launch options on your scene delegate. Here is a quick example:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {                
          if let response = connectionOptions.notificationResponse {
             //get your launch info from here
             let location = response.notification.request.content.userInfo[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.location]
    ...
          }
        }
```